# Scala use ML to find outliers in a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

this question is gonna be a little vague, but I cant seem to find any concrete example online.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html

From the above spark docs, I can see multiple ways of training and predict anomaly/outliers with Mllib library. However, every single one of those examples only involve numbers or at most 2 columns of data.

I can't figure out how to train and predict on a data set with more values and etc...

Let's say if I wanted to use the clustering method to find outliers to my data, and my data looks like the following in a Dataframe:

```
UserId   |   Department   |   Date   |   Item   |   Cost
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   115
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   150
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   900
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-23   |  Iphone  |   85
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-20   |  Iphone  |   120
user2    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   600
user2    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   550
user2    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   600
user2    |   Electronic   |  11-23   |  Iphone  |   575
user2    |   Electronic   |  11-20   |  Iphone  |   570
....
```

There will be millions of data like this across months. 
I want to research across the pattern of the users in the past X months and constantly updating my model every day with new data. So something like

```
user1    |   Electronic   |  11-19   |  Iphone  |   900
```

should be considered an outlier

How can I apply any of the above supervised learning methods on this type of datasets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using Spark 0.9 (current version is 2.2)? The site you have quoted is showing a kMeans example [1]. The parameter *parsedData* can have more than two columns, but kMeans in Spark 0.9 can only handle double values [2].

Also the other examples can have more than two columns [3]. The label parameter could be an ongoing number and features are your listed data, but like kMeans spark 0.9 is only able to handle double values.

Looking at the other avaiable classes of 0.9 api let's me assume the spark 0.9 was only able to handle double values. If you want to handle the data liked you have showed above, you should consider to use a more recent version of spark.

[1] https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html#clustering-1

[2] https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$

[3] https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

Comment: Hi, I am currently using spark 2.2 now, but I still cant find any examples online can you please provide some?